# How to paralelling NamedParameterJdbcTemplate calls over a array using parallelStream()?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Using SpringFramework I want iterate over a array of longs (IDs) and make a `select` query on the database SQL. The query have a `IN (...)` clause to put the IDs, but it have a limit of 1000 items. The array of all contents have a limit of 5000 items so the code grouping it on 1000 items by time, and I want make it parallel. The problem is that on the practice it is executed in series and not parallel.

Code:

```
    @Transactional
    public List<GenericRecord> process(final Collection<Long> idsList) {
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        final StopWatch tookTotal = new StopWatch();
        tookTotal.start();

        idsList.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 1000)).values().parallelStream().forEach(lot -> {
            /*
                 lot -> Array[Long] (1000)
             */
            final StopWatch took = new StopWatch();
            took.start();
            List<GenericRecord> fetchedItems = fetchItemsFromIds(lot);
            took.stop();
            LOGGER.info("M=processTransactions, SELECT QUERY => Count: {}, Took: {}ms", fetchedItems.size(), took.getLastTaskTimeMillis());
        });

        tookTotal.stop();
        LOGGER.info("M=process, TotalSize: {}, TookTotal: {}ms", idsList.size(), tookTotal.getLastTaskTimeMillis());

        return new ArrayList<>(); // just to works.
    }

    private List<GenericRecord> fetchItemsByIds(final Collection<Long> idsList) {
        final MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("ids", idsList);
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(searchQuery, mapSqlParameterSource, new MyGenericRecordRowMapper());
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
SELECT QUERY => Count: 1001, Took: 5231ms
SELECT QUERY => Count: 1000, Took: 5901ms
SELECT QUERY => Count: 1000, Took: 5290ms
SELECT QUERY => Count: 1000, Took: 4818ms
SELECT QUERY => Count: 1000, Took: 5358ms
M=process, TotalSize: 5000, TookTotal: 21373ms
```

Clearly it is not executing paralelling, its look execute on series. Or, I don't know something about it. I know that have a limit of Jdbc connections but shoud be more than 5.

PS1.: I don't know the reason that the first select get 1001 items instead 1000, but is not problem so far.
PS2.: The goal is gain on performance and speed.

Comment: It's not possible, Oracle simply doesn't allow it. The way you are doing it currently i.e. putting it into chunks of 1000 is the only solution.

Comment: But no erros happens and no exceptions. I mean that should fire a exception on tries access many concurrent times JDBC.

Comment: It's because your code runs 5 statements each containing 1000 ids concurrently. The problem would be if you tried doing it in one statement with more than 1000.

Comment: It's not my problem. The problem is the parallelism java.

Answer (score 0):

By the data you posted there seems to be some parallelism and even some performance gain: 5231ms+5901ms+5290ms+4818ms+5358ms=26598ms > 21373ms.

Please note that since using a parallel approach has an overhead, timing is a very poor indicator of actual parallel execution and some other tools would be more suited. `parallelStream()` is not garanteed to return a parallel stream (as it seems to be doing in your case), and as far as I know is intended more as an easy way to parallelize than as an efficient one. Depending on the specific case you may get better improvements using threads and eventually a thread pool or you may get no improvement at all.

Comment: For some reason `parallelStream` protect me of `sessions out` of JDBC connection. Using pure Threads I got the exception because many connections of JDBC is openend and exceptions are fired.